# Pixel is not paired with a product catalog

Tags: facebook

I am doing Facebook dynamic ads management. I already created product catalog and uploaded into business manager. I also added pixel tracking code to my website pages. But when viewing the page i got the error: 'Pixel is not paired with a product catalog '.

I found the solution to this as seen in the image below
[image]

I followed the steps in that. But i cant find a button like 'Associate Pixels' in my settings page. 
Does anyone know why i have no button named 'Associate Pixels' in my settings page?

Comment: I don't see a programming question here, so this is probably off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The business page was not linked to my ad account and the pixel can only be created in the ad account. So business was not finding the pixel to link the product list to. I linked the business page to the ad account and the problem solved.

Comment: How did you do this i.e. " I linked the business page to the ad account and the problem solved.". In business.facebook.com or in the Facebook Page's settings somewhere?

Comment: In my case was that I have installed the tool when I was logged in into my personal account Ads, so the one with my fb profile, instead the pixel event is tracked into the page ads manager and is firing correctly. So this could be also a reason

Answer (score 3):

I believe the button was renamed to "Associate Sources" since app events can also be associated with a product catalog as well.

[image]

Comment: you are right. But my problem was i have no permission to do that. It was not linked to any external sources. Now its ok.